# How to fix java.sql.SQLException: Column not found trying to extract Mysql table in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Program:

```
private void loadData(Connection connection) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Integer> TID=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String>ItemSet=new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
        String sql="Select distinct TID from transaction";
        ResultSet SetTid=statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while(SetTid.next())
        {
            int initialTID=SetTid.getInt("TID");
            TID.add(initialTID);
        }
        for(int initialTID : TID)
        {
            String sqlitem="Select ItemSet from transaction where TID="+initialTID;
            ResultSet setItem=statement.executeQuery(sqlitem);
            while(setItem.next())
            {
                String items=setItem.getString(sqlitem);%%LINE 57
                ItemSet.add(items);

            }
            InItemSet.add(ItemSet);
            setItem.close();

        }
```

First query Sql is returning proper value but second query sqlite is showing column not found, the table name is transaction with 2 column TID and ItemSet.

Error log is:
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'Select distinct ItemSet from transaction  where TID=184' not found.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:548)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:852)
    at Apriori.loadData(Apriori.java:57)
    at Apriori.main(Apriori.java:28)

Line 28 from Main program

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    Apriori apriori=new Apriori();
    System.out.print("Please select a transaction database from 1-5");
    String database=scanner.next();
    try {
        Connection connection=DatabaseConnection.getConnection(database);
        apriori.loadData(connection);   >>> LINE 28
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: The error suggests that on line 28 of `Apriori`, in the method `main`, you are using `resultSet.getString("Select distinct ItemSet from transaction where TID=184")` which is unlikely to be an actual column name. As far as I can tell you don't show that line 28 here, because you're showing a method called `loadData` and not a method called `main`. Please post a [mre] and make sure that the exception you post is consistent with the code you post.

Comment: As an aside, you're executing two statements that are probably better executed as one statement

Comment: Hey Mark,ItemSet is one othe column and I have called the method loadData from Main.

Comment: Please review the edited program I have added the portion from Main

Comment: I see now that I was misreading the stacktrace due to a missing linebreak due to the formatting of the stacktrace. Does the code you show of `loadData` include line 57? Because I guess it will be `setItem.getString(sqlitem)` instead of `setItem.getString("ItemSet")`, but no such line is shown.

Comment: Yes updated loadData including Line 57.

Comment: Yes Mark,Line 57 is setItem.getString(sqlitem)

Comment: So, the problem is that you are using `setItem.getString(sqlitem)` (`sqlitem` contains your query, not a column name) instead of `setItem.getString("ItemSet")`.

Comment: Awesome...Thanks ton...It worked,I did understand what was wrong,Thanks Mark u saved :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for prompt response:)